# php get `date("Ymd")-1`

Tags: php, date

I store some `error_log` with date for their name. like `20120827.txt`

Now I write some php script for view the `error_log`.

I need do some judgment:

```
if(file_exists(date("Ymd").'.txt')){ 
   $html = file_get_contents(date("Ymd").'.txt');
}else{
   $html = file_get_contents((date("Ymd")-1).'.txt');//load yesterday's `error_log`.
}
```

But this not suit the date like `20120801.txt`, How to do `date("Ymd")-1`?

I tried `date("Ymd", (strtotime($date) . " -1 day"));// return:19700101`

Comment: What about when the last log written is two days old?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want yesterday's date you can do

```
date("Ymd", time() - 3600*24);
```

Or you could use the `DateTime` object:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->modify("-1 day");
echo $date->format("Ymd");
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this... Simplest one...

```
date('Ymd',strtotime( "yesterday" ));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use PHP's [`mktime`](http://php.net/mktime) to get a very-precise date:

```
date('Ymd', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d') - 1, date('Y')));
```

Comment: @Eric Yeah, if the day-value is `0`, which `(1 - 1)` will give, it will wrap to the last day of the previous month (which is "yesterday").

Comment: Just checking it wraps around.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `strtotime` like this:

```
date('Ymd', strtotime('-1 day'));
```

Here is a paste with output: http://codepad.org/iD7M9VN7